# Redshift analyze compression: result output

Tags: amazon-redshift

I need to use the outputs of 'analyze compression' in Redshift stored procedure, is there a way to store the results of 'analyze compression' to a temp table?

Comment: Do you want to achieve this via stored procedure? Or are you open to using it via shell scripts? or python?

Comment: I had a requirement to do it via stored procedure, in the meantime I did it in Python but still if there is a way to achieve it via stored procedure it would fit my requirement the best.

Comment: You can't save it. And I think you can't even run the analyze command via stored procedure(Im sure vacuum will not run, so it may not run analyze as well)